# Unable to replace backslash from a string using replace function in python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to remove the backslash from a string in python. The code I have used is the following:

```
vb='\x82\x81'
vb.replace('\\',"")

The output I am getting is the same string:

'\x82\x81'

The output I want is:

'x82x81'
```

Comment: `vb` contains no backslashes to replace. The source code you wrote to construct it contains backslashes, and the string's `repr` representation (displayed if you examine the string interactively without using `print`) contains backslashes, but the actual string contains no backslashes.

Comment: strings are immutable. use `vb = vb.replace('\\',"")`

Comment: @ user2357112  The first character itself is a backslash. @HenryYik I did that too, but it is not reflecting any change.

Comment: `print('\x82\x81')` – no backslash. You need to distinguish between the *string literal representation* and the *actual contents of the string.* Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). What are you *really* trying to do here?

Comment: @LuckySunda: No it's not. The first character is U+0082 BREAK PERMITTED HERE (or if this is Python 2, the first byte is hex 82, and it's arguable whether this should be described as a character). The second character you wrote in the string literal is a backslash (and the first character you wrote is `'`), but neither of those characters end up in the string.

Comment: can you tell what vb looks like to you in the comment? I have typed vb='\x82\x81'

Comment: What you have typed are the escape sequences for the bytes `82` and `81`; interpreted as UTF-8 that represents the characters ``. (If this doesn't show up as anything meaningful to you, yeah, that's correct.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You *could* define the variable as a raw string:

```
>>> vb=r'\x82\x81'
>>> vb.replace('\\',"")
'x82x81'
```

Since the answer solved the OP's issue and somebody is seemingly upset that it worked (thanks for the corner case), here's a couple other solutions in the event of "actual input from a file or a web request or whatever" (the last one should be most versatile):

```
>>> vb='\x82\x81'
>>> vb=repr(vb).strip("'")
>>> vb.replace('\\',"")
'x82x81'
```

In the case of `\x09\x0a\x5c\x61`, etc.

```
>>> vb='\x09\x0a\x5c\x61\x80\x08\x90\x00\x10\x01'
>>> ''.join([ hex(ord(b))[1:].zfill(3).replace('0x','x0') for b in vb ])
'x09x0ax5cx61x80x08x90x00x10x01'
```

Yep, it's ugly, but works (although couldn't test much) — there might be a simpler way, meh.

Comment: @LuckySunda: It may have "worked" for this case, but if all you had to deal with was hardcoded string literals, you would have just written `vb='x82x81'` from the start instead of trying to go through `str.replace`. When you have to deal with actual input from a file or a web request or whatever, you're not going to have a string literal to stick an `r` on, and you're not going to be able to do this.

Comment: With `vb=repr(vb).replace('\\',"")`, an input of `'\x09\x0a\x5c\x61'` becomes `"'tna'"` instead of `'x09x0ax5cx61'`. Also, the `'\x82\x81'` actually becomes `"'x82x81'"` rather than what you posted.

Comment: I am reading inputs from a file only, for which I used the above code to replace all backslashes. But when I found out that backslash are still there, I tried it separately then also it was not working. I wanted the output to be simply x82x81, which was not coming by using relpace method alone. repr() is also working. Thanks